# Distance in arrays

Tags: python, function, distance

So I have to code a function that calculates the distance between two points - p1 and p2 - from an array with several points. Each point represents a square with 20 m on each side.
the distance should be something like:

```
d = sqrt(w(r1 −r2))^2 + (w(c1 −c2))^2 + (a1 −a2)^2 )
```

Where w is 20, the side of the square, r1 and r2, the row's index, c1 and c2 the column's index, and a1 and a2 the value of each point.

the array of distances is:

```
test = [ [206,205,204,190,208], [190,194,206,197,203], [196,196,205,201,193], [194,199,199,206,205], [192,196,195,201,193], [194,199,200,200,205], [196,196,195,200,193] ]
```

Can someone help on this easy one?

Comment: Show the array of points

Comment: Python has lists, not arrays (unless you have imported some module)

Comment: my theacher gave me those "testS" as  the distance points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to import sqrt from the math libary
squares can either be calculated by multiplying the value with itself (r2-r1)(r2-r1) or by using pow from the math libary as well. (r2-r1)^2 does not work.

strictly speaking A is not an array but a list (rows) of lists (columns).
But you can thing of it as a kind of array anyway. You get values of it by using two indices A[row_index][column_index]

```
from math import sqrt, pow

A = [[206,205,204,190,208],
     [190,194,206,197,203],
     [196,196,205,201,193],
     [194,199,199,206,205],
     [192,196,195,201,193],
     [194,199,200,200,205],
     [196,196,195,200,193]]

W = 20


def distance(r1, c1, r2, c2):
    # get a values for point 1 and 2
    a1 = A[r1][c1]
    a2 = A[r2][c2]
    # calculate the distance
    d = sqrt(pow(W*(r2-r1), 2) + pow(W*(c2-c1), 2) + pow(a2-a1, 2))
    return d


print(distance(0,0,4,4))
>>> 113.88
```